# How to activate https on ec2 for express app

Tags: express, amazon-ec2, https, dns

I am use ec2 for my express app also I have domain from godaddy. Now I can connect to godaddy but it runs with http and brings not secure on left side of browser' url bar. So I need hide port from url and activate https.I tried to google,but can't find article for this part.What is my next steps? Thanks for help and for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to get a free SSL Certificate.
2. The easiest way would be to register your domain to Cloudflare, though your traffic will be redirected through Cloudflare's servers, you will get full SSL for your website. [Guide](https://pushalert.co/blog/free-ssl-easy-setup-guide/).

Comment: I've tried get certificate from aws, but they haven't receive me anything?But I'll try it again.

Comment: Then go for the second option. :) My own websites run behind Cloudflare. Cloudflare is a very flexible DNS provider.

Comment: Thank you The Infected Drake